# How to make a single member of an anonymous union public?

Tags: c++

I'd like to use a union with some public members and some that are not. Is this possible without getters or const references?

```
class Test {
    union {
        int arr[2];
        /*public*/ struct {
            int x;
            int y;
        };
    };
};

int main() {
    Test test;
    test.x = 0; // want to work
    test.arr[0] = 1; // don't want to work
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `union`s default to `public` access. Have you tried declaring the private members `private`, not just (redundantly) declaring the public members `public`?

Comment: While anonymous unions are allowed in C++, anonymous structs are not allowed (such as the member of your anonymous union).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - This is incorrect, unions accept the specifier that they are declared in. a class starts implicitly private, so a union declared in a class is restricted. https://onlinegdb.com/vxqLDiITV

Comment: @eerorika - This is incorrect, anonymous structs within unions have been supported since the first revision of c++. https://onlinegdb.com/hoCzF6x7n

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: Pretty sure that's because you can't access the `union` definition itself. The problem isn't the access specifiers of the `union` members, it's that the `union` as a whole is `private` to the class. I think you'd need a `public` `union` to make the union itself exposed, then limit access on the members of the `union`.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis Why do you think it's incorrect? It's never been supported in standard C++.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - that's what I was originally hoping would work, but when I try something like this https://onlinegdb.com/XNzwBFqQe, it fails. `error: private member 'int Test::<anonymous union>::arr [2]' in anonymous union [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @eerorika - navigate to the link on my previous comment and hit run near the top. Usage of anonymous structs in anonymous unions works fine.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis Just because a program runs, doesn't mean that it conforms to the standard. You're using a language extension.

Comment: @eerorika - didn't know that. I have a lot of code in production that depends on that and I've never ran into a compiler that didn't support it by default. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis -- anonymous structs are a Microsoft thing, not standard C++. They're used extensively in the Windows headers, so compilers that support Windows have to provide them. There is no formal specification for what they do, and, as I vaguely recall, if you go beyond the most basic uses, the can have very weird semantics with Microsoft's compilers.